# Using Stash conditional to interrogate Solspace Tag Related Entries count

Tags: stash, solspace-tag

I'm using a Solspace Tag - Related Entries to show tagged entries. On the page, I show the first 3 channel entries and then wish to show a link to view more entries, but only if there are more than 3 entries to show.

I'm struggling to get a conditional working to show/hide the link based on the count of items in the results, while using Stash.

Here's my template;

```
{exp:stash:set name="itinerary_events"}
    {exp:tag:related_entries
        channel="event"
        orderby="event_date"
        sort="asc"
        limit="3"
        paginate="bottom"
    }
    {title}
    {/exp:tag:related_entries}
{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:set name="itinerary_events_more"}
    {exp:tag:related_entries
        channel="event"
        orderby="event_date"
        sort="asc"
        limit="15"
        paginate="bottom"
        offset="3"
    }
    {stash:count}{count}{/stash:count}
    {title}
    {/exp:tag:related_entries}
{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:set_list name="itinerary-vars" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="{channel}"
        status="open"
        limit="1"
    }
        {stash:tag}{exp:tag:tags entry_id="{entry_id}" limit="1" websafe_separator="-"}{tag}{/exp:tag:tags}{/stash:tag}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:set name="content"}

    {exp:stash:get_list name="itinerary-vars"}

<div class="box">
    {if "{exp:stash:get name='count'}" > "3"}<a href="#">View all</a>{/if}

    {exp:stash:get name="itinerary_things"}

    {exp:stash:get name="itinerary_things_more"}
</div>

    {/exp:stash:get_list}

{/exp:stash:set}
```

I would be grateful if anyone might be able to help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is about the View All link setup, I removed the `itinerary-vars` set_list. There's no need to run your `exp:tag:related_entries` tag twice when you're using Stash. Let Stash do the work to cut down on db queries.

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="itinerary_events" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:tag:related_entries
        channel="event"
        orderby="event_date"
        sort="asc"
        limit="4"
    }
        {stash:event_title}{title}{/stash:event_title}
        {stash:event_count}{count}{/stash:event_count}
    {/exp:tag:related_entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:set name="content"}
    <div class="box">
        {exp:stash:get_list name="itinerary_events"}
            {if "{event_count}" == 4}<a href="#">View all</a>{/if}
            {if "{event_count}" <= 3}<h1>{event_title}</h1>{/if}
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
    </div>
{/exp:stash:set}
```